# Overriding app engine template block inside an if

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a block 'left_area' defined in a base appengine template

```
{% block left_area %}
   <div class="span3">
     Left area content
   </div> 
{% endblock %}
```

In a child template, I want to override this block inside an if

```
{% if not user %}
  {% block left_area %}
    <div class="span2">
    </div> 
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This is not working for some reason. Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe that django conditional blocks are not allowed by design, See this discussion for detaisl: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-developers/_02s99mocmI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jinja you can solve it with super(), which renders the parent block:

```
{% block left_area %}
    {% if not user %}
        <div class="span2">
        </div>
    {% else %}        
        {{ super() }}
    {% endif %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed by using jinja2 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: In django you can use: block.super