# Is there a way to pass variables into Jinja2 parents?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to pass some variables from the child page to the template. This is my python code:

```
    if self.request.url.find("&try") == 1:
        isTrying = False
    else:
        isTrying = True

    page_values = {
        "trying": isTrying
    }

    page = jinja_environment.get_template("p/index.html")
    self.response.out.write(page.render(page_values))
```

The template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/template.css"></link>
    <title>{{ title }} | SST QA</title>

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  {% block head %}{% endblock head %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if not trying %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Redirects user to maintainence page
    window.location.href = "construct"
    </script>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and the child:

```
{% extends "/templates/template.html" %}
{% set title = "Welcome" %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The problem is, I want to pass the variable "trying" into the parent, is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand your problem. When you pass variables to the context (as you do with trying) these variables will be available in the child and the parent.
To pass title to the parent, you have to use inheritance, sometimes in combination with super : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#super-blocks

See also this question: [Overriding app engine template block inside an if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137628/overriding-app-engine-template-block-inside-an-if/13144105#13144105)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I have figured out the problem. The answer is simple - don't. It gives me a lot of problems.

Comment: "The answer is simple - don't"

Instead of using a variable, I usually add a nested block into the parent block, then filling it in the child.

Comment: The answer of sscalvo works, though! (and it's useful for some niche cases)

Answer (score 18):

The example on the Jinja2 Tips and Tricks page explains this perfectly, http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#base-template. Essentially, if you have a base template

```
**base.html**
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MegaCorp -{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and a child template

```
**child.html**
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Home page {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
... stuff here
{% endblock %}
```

whatever python function calls render_template("child.html") will return the html page

```
**Rendered Page**
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MegaCorp - Home page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            stuff here...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this should probably be marked as the correct answer based on how the question is framed up.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, that is whether is possible to pass a variable from the child to the parent. Something like `{% extends "base.html" is_trying=True %}`, and then read `is_trying` inside the parent.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to declare that variable **before** extending the template, so the extended template will have access to to the variable `trying`

```
{% set trying = True %}  <----------- declare variable

{% extends "/templates/template.html" %}
{% set title = "Welcome" %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Few years later but hoping it may help latecomers

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Was trying to set up a global namespace for any page derived from a base template, and this was the only way to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you are looking to highlight active menus in the base layout and you need something like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% set active = "clients" %}
```

then use can use "active" inside base.html