# How to set a variable in a child template in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

[This question was asked once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254308/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-jinja2-parents), but it didn't answer the question, so I'm re-asking it directly.

I'm trying to set a variable in a child template, so that it changes how a parent template renders things.  In this question, I show a practical example.

My site has 2 kinds of templates.  One that displays the content narrow and a full width template.

(I snipped out all the complexity so that I can show you a simple example)

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
        <div id="pageContentContainer">
            <div class="row">
            {% if fullwidth %}
                <div class="col-12">fffff
                    {{super()}}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-9">
                    {{super()}}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**page-fullwidth.html**

```
{% extends "page.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% set fullwidth = true %}
    {{super()}}
{% endblock %}
```

This doesn't work.  The variable `fullwidth` is not True in the parent template.

Is there some other practical way to do this?  I don't want to repeat the contents of `page.html` in `page-fullwidth.html`. (In the real one, this file is more complex.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost right.  This is the answer.  The variable setter needs to be outside the block

**page-fullwidth.html**

```
{% extends "page.html" %}

{% set fullwidth = true %}

{% block content %}
    {{super()}}
{% endblock %}
```