# Jinja active_page not working when within an included file

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

So i have a working layout `_layout.html` (using Jinja2 v2.6 and Flask) which is including my header with `{% include 'header.html' %}` and the body contents with `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` (in that order).

header.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/about" {% if active_page == 'about' %} class="selected" {% endif %}>ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

about.html

```
{% extends "_layout.html" %}
{% set active_page = 'about' %}

{% block content %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that as the child templates are global and executed before the layout template is evaluated so the `class="selected"` are not being added as the `header.html` template does not have the active_page in its context.

If i place the header.html contents in the main layout everything works fine, how can i get this to work using the include and structure i have?

EDIT:

I have also tried `{% include 'header.html' with context %}` and `{% from 'header.html' import input with context %}` both do not work.

Comment: You can put the header is a block, or have a look at super.

Comment: Im not sure this is the answer as i really need this to be a kind of include so i can use the header.html around the site while maintaining the structure i have. I don think its possible to create custom blocks?

Comment: Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137628/overriding-app-engine-template-block-inside-an-if . And use this to override the base header in your childs if needed.

Comment: As [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope) says: `Starting with Jinja 2.2 you can explicitly specify that variables are available in a block by setting the block to “scoped” by adding the scoped modifier to a block declaration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest work around could be to just use JavaScript (JQuery in this case):

**JQuery:**

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname;

$('nav ul li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == currentPage){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

This function will add a selected class to the `<a>` tag that matches the current window location.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

in my _mainlayout

```
 {% block stylesheets %}
    Links to stylesheets go here
 {% endblock %}

 {% block main_body_area %}
        Replace with your html body
 {% endblock %}

 {% block scripts %}
    Add js scripts here
 {% endblock %}
```

Then in the child templates simply do the following:

```
{% extends "_mainlayout.html" %}

 {% block stylesheets %}   
    <style sheets go here/>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block main_body_area %}
    <your page content here/>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block scripts %}
    add any js scripts here
 {% endblock %}
```

You can then add your active_page in the head section which in the example I gave you is where I keep the stylesheets. I do it this way because in my _mainlayout file I have a standard css stylesheet which is used across all pages and then if I need additional page specific layouts I include it in that particular page if not just leave it blank.

The same goes with the js files I don't want to load scripts on pages that dont need them so it makes it easy to include them on pages that do require specific js files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you think this can be done using an include though?

Comment: Ok so I tried and tried for several hours now with no luck! I will give it a go in the morning with a more fresh mind!

Comment: Thank you i appreciate your efforts, i've been stuck with this one for a few days now. There must be a work around!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in Jinja2 **version 2.8**. Upgrading it to **version 2.9** solved the problem.